# Cannot see usb devices on Windows guest

Tags: virtualbox, usb-drive

I have VirtualBox (VB) 5.1.22 installed on Fedora 25 and I installed Windows 8.1 Pro within VB.

I belong to group `vboxusers`:

```
$ id
uid=1010(fuji) gid=1025(staff) groups=1025(staff),1030(vboxusers)
```

and I still cannot see the USB devices that should be listed in the "Devices/USB" menu:
[image: No usb devices connected]

Selecting USB 2.0 Controller does not fix the problem.
Pluging my USB 3.0 key in a USB 2.0 slot does not fix the problem either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I also have this problem: I am a member of vboxusers and I can see the devices being created under /dev/vboxusb/... with the correct group applied.  I can even run the "vboxmanage list usbhost" and see all my USB devices - I just can't see them in the GUI, or from inside the guest VM :-(

Comment: No, I haven't solved the problem yet. I'll try again monday with VB 5.2.0.

Comment: I've been seeing this problem with VirtualBox 5.2.1, so I doubt that's going to solve the issue.  For my own purposes I've switched to using KVM, which has no problem handling this, but with that one I haven't figured out how to make KVM handle unplugging/plugging my USB device without restarting the VM.

Comment: @karora I solved it finally. The vboxusers group id displayed by command `id` (here 1030) was not the same as the one in the file `/etc/group`. That group id 1030 was set up in FreeIpa and given to all users. I removed it from FreeIpa and did a `usermod -G staff,vboxusers fuji` to add user fuji to group vboxusers that is in file /etc/group.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021300

Answer (score 4):

Edit your virtual machine -> usb -> Click on the little USB logo with the Green plus signal. Add the usb device you want to show to your guest OS. Be happy. :)

If you see them in the list, but they fail in installing driver, check to see you have USB2.0 enabled in virtualbox settings. USB1.0 is set by default and will not be able to install USB 2.0 drivers. The program may prompt you to install an extension pack for this. Once USB 2.0 (or 3.0 if you have a USB3.0) is enabled, the USB should attach and proper drivers installed.

If that does not work, you will probably need to disable that device inside host and enable it in guest. There is an awesome and complete tutorial at Ask Ubuntu, related to this question:

- **Ask Ubuntu:** [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

I know that i should not link external how-tos here, but this is a matter of not repeating something that other people have already answered inside SE sites.

Another detail is that, for Windows guests the following limitations apply:

- Windows 7 needs an [additional driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/65855/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver) for USB 3.0 support.
- Windows 10 does not accept an NTFS formatted USB pen drive.

Comment: There is nothing in the "USB with the Green plus signal". So I cannot enable anything in the guest. And I made sure the USB key was not mounted in the host.

Comment: And have you followed all the tips that are on the Ask Ubuntu reference link?

Comment: I'm under Fedora 25 and I enabled support for USB 3.0 . My key is USB 3.0 . The mouse tooltip says "No supported device connected to the host pc."

Comment: The extension pack for 5.1.22 is installed. I'm in group vboxusers. I have support for USB 3.0 enabled. And I do not see any key listed in the devices/USB menu.

Comment: OK. Usb is not mounted, but it is listed under `/dev/sdx`?

Comment: Yes they are:

$ ll /dev/sdf*

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 80 May 29 15:58 /dev/sdf

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 81 May 29 15:58 /dev/sdf1

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 82 May 29 15:58 /dev/sdf2

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 83 May 29 15:58 /dev/sdf3

Comment: What about if you eject the device before mapping inside vbox: `eject /dev/sdf` and then try to add it to guest...

Comment: Nothing appears in the Devices/USB menu.

Comment: Does "vboxmanage list usbhost" list your USB devices?

Comment: Re your comment, " i should not link external how-tos here," you are actually supposed to link to sources, and also excerpt/copy enough to get the solution if the source page changes later. I don't see this explicitly in the "How to Ask a Good Question" pages but it's a desired practice on SO and other SE sites. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh, yeah and thanks for the great link that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to run `modprobe -r usb_storage` to get the host to give up the drive.